# Why am I receiving a 400 Error when trying to fetch data from the NSRDB API

Tags: python, pandas, api, csv, urllib

I am attempting to fetch data from the NSRDB PSM API via a formatted URL but I keep getting a HTTP 400 Error and I can't get a specific reason from the stack trace.

The following is the code:

```
# Declare all variables as strings. Spaces must be replaced with '+', i.e., change 'John Smith' to 'John+Smith'.
# Define the lat, long of the location and the year
#Using UWI, St. Augustine Campus as the Target, 10.6416° N, 61.3995° W
lat, lon, year = 10.6416, 61.3995, 2019

# You must request an NSRDB api key from the link above(replace this with your API key
api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Set the attributes to extract (e.g., dhi, ghi, etc.), separated by commas.
attributes = 'ghi,dhi,dni,wind_speed,air_temperature,solar_zenith_angle'

# Set leap year to true or false. True will return leap day data if present, false will not.
leap_year = 'false'

# Set time interval in minutes, i.e., '30' is half hour intervals. Valid intervals are 30 & 60.
interval = '30'

# Specify Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), 'true' will use UTC, 'false' will use the local time zone of the data.
# NOTE: In order to use the NSRDB data in SAM, you must specify UTC as 'false'. SAM requires the data to be in the
# local time zone.
utc = 'false'

# Your full name, use '+' instead of spaces.
your_name = 'Shankar+Ramharack'

# Your reason for using the NSRDB.
reason_for_use = 'research'

# Your affiliation
your_affiliation = 'UWI'

# Your email address
your_email = 'XXXXXXX'

# Please join our mailing list so we can keep you up-to-date on new developments.
mailing_list = 'false'

# Declare url string
url = 'https://developer.nrel.gov/api/solar/nsrdb_psm3_download.csv?wkt=POINT({lon}%20{lat})&names={year}&leap_day={leap}&interval={interval}&utc={utc}&full_name={name}&email={email}&affiliation={affiliation}&mailing_list={mailing_list}&reason={reason}&api_key={api}&attributes={attr}'.format(year=year, lat=lat, lon=lon, leap=leap_year, interval=interval, utc=utc, name=your_name, email=your_email, mailing_list=mailing_list, affiliation=your_affiliation, reason=reason_for_use, api=api_key, attr=attributes)
# Return just the first 2 lines to get metadata:
info = pd.read_csv(url, nrows=1)
# See metadata for specified properties, e.g., timezone and elevation
timezone, elevation = info['Local Time Zone'], info['Elevation']
```

I followed the method specified on their page: [here](https://nsrdb.nrel.gov/data-sets/api-instructions.html). I am not sure if I am making a pandas error in reading or a specific python error. I am relatively new to the language.

Answer (score 0):

I got feedback from the devs and it was an issue on their site, they are currently updating the documentation. To access data use the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://developer.nrel.gov/api/nsrdb/v2/solar/psm3-download.csv?wkt=POINT({lon}%20{lat})&names={year}&leap_day={leap}&interval={interval}&utc={utc}&full_name={name}&email={email}&affiliation={affiliation}&mailing_list={mailing_list}&reason={reason}&api_key={api}&attributes={attr}'.format(year=year, lat=lat, lon=lon, leap=leap_year, interval=interval, utc=utc, name=your_name, email=your_email, mailing_list=mailing_list, affiliation=your_affiliation, reason=reason_for_use, api=api_key, attr=attributes), skiprows=2)
```

An alternate method of obtaining NSRDB data is to use the wrapper functions from the pvlib library. The source code can be found [here](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pvlib/iotools/psm3.html). Using pvlib.iotools.get_psm3() function, data can be queried from the PSM model API.

Use the latest release for best performance.